# Pronunciation of "I" vowel name in fast speech

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, vowels, songs, fast-speech-rules

I'm not a native english speaker. 
I was wondering what is the right way to pronunce the "I" (/aɪ/) vowel name in fast speech.
Perhaps i'm confused, but sometimes i hear /a/. Like in the Arctic Monkeys song "I bet that you good look on the dance floor". Just in the chorus, i hear something like /abet.../ more than /aɪbet/.

And other times i even hear only a schwa /ə/ sound. Like in the White Stripes song "Fell in love with a girl". Over the last of the second verse
Jack says "i seid it once before..." i hear /əsed/ more than /aɪsed/ or /ased/.
I want to know what you thinking about.

If i write down this in the wrong place or if i had a grammar or spell mistake i beg you apologise me.

Comment: A bit more context would get you a better answer. In British English the *I* can take on several contractions and twists. Less so in American English. If you could tell us where you hear this then a more precise answer could be made.

Comment: I have added some examples now. By the way, for some reason i could not write hello down. So, hello.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between /ʌɪ/ and /aɪ/ in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547469/what-is-the-difference-between-%ca%8c%c9%aa-and-a%c9%aa-in-english)

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the site! There is no real 'right' way to pronounce *I* in fast speech, let alone song. I can only say that the allophones you have heard, in the given positions in those sentences, are quite common. There might be other options as well.

The faster a vowel is pronounced, the more likely it is to be reduced, from /aɪ/ to /a/ or /ʌ/ and even /ə/. I'd like to think reduction is much less common in classical music, but that is probably an exaggeration.